# Poner porcentajes en dos ion range sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Estoy usando esta librería: [Ion Range Slider](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html)

Estoy tratando de bindear dos sliders, y que se muevan a cierto porcentaje cuando uno de ellos es manipulado.

Dejo ejemplo

```js
$(function(){

  $("#foo").ionRangeSlider({
    type: "single",
    grid: true,
    min: 1,
    max: 200,
    from: 50,
    keyboard: true,
    onFinish: function(data) {
      var percent = 100 - Math.floor(data.from_percent);

      if( data.input[0].id === 'foo' ){
        priceSlider.update({
          from: percent
        });
      }

      else{
        timeSlider.update({
          from: percent
        });
      }
    },
  });
  
    $("#bar").ionRangeSlider({
    type: "single",
    grid: true,
    min: 500,
    max: 1000,
    from: 50,
    keyboard: true,
    onFinish: function(data) {
      var percent = 100 - Math.floor(data.from_percent);

      if( data.input[0].id === 'foo' ){
        priceSlider.update({
          from: percent
        });
      }

      else{
        timeSlider.update({
          from: percent
        });
      }
    },
  });
  
      var priceSlider = $('#bar').data("ionRangeSlider"),
      timeSlider = $('#foo').data("ionRangeSlider");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.2.0/js/ion.rangeSlider.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.2.0/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.2.0/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinHTML5.min.css">

<label>Price</label>
<input type="text" class="slider" id="bar">

<label>Time</label>
<input type="text" class="slider" id="foo">
```

Lo que necesito es, cuando la barra con id "bar" se mueva, poner "foo" al sentido contrario, por ejemplo, si "bar" quedó en 75% "foo" debería de ponerse en 25%. No lo he conseguido.

Bienvenidas sugerencias

Comment: Quizá me equivoque pero los imputs no cambian de valor al cambiar el valor de los sliders, me equivoco? no se si te interese saber ya que imagino quieras obtener los valores después.

Answer (score 1):

Prácticamente lo tenías, sólamente te faltaba cambiar el `from_percent` por `from` en el `update` del `slider` y en la resta de porcentajes:

```js
$(function(){

  $(".slider").ionRangeSlider({
type: "single",
grid: true,
min: 1,
max: 100,
from: 50,
keyboard: true,
onChange: function(data) {
  var percent = 100 - Math.floor(data.from);
  if( data.input[0].id === 'foo' ){
    priceSlider.update({
      from: percent
    });
  }
  else{
    timeSlider.update({
      from: percent
    });
  }
},
  });
  
  var priceSlider = $('#bar').data("ionRangeSlider"),
  timeSlider = $('#foo').data("ionRangeSlider");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.2.0/js/ion.rangeSlider.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.2.0/css/ion.rangeSlider.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ion-rangeslider/2.2.0/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinHTML5.min.css">

<label>Price</label>
<input type="text" class="slider" id="bar">

<label>Time</label>
<input type="text" class="slider" id="foo">
```

Comment: Tienes razón, error mío, por querer hacer un ejemplo rápido en el Fiddle olvidé que los Sliders tienen valores máximos y mínimos distintos, ya edité para simular el problema que tengo.